# Jquery UI tabs fails for large div data in IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, model-view-controller

The main problem was that my mvc web app was dead slow (and often crashed) in IE but it worked fine in FireFox, Chrome and Opera.
(IE is a hell of a browser!)

So I was researching what was the problem and found the cause that this jQuery function was the culprit.

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
```

Not to blame jQuery though. Cause one of my tabs has got a div that amounts to 26MB in size! IE could handle it when reduced the size of the div. But the business logics don't allow me to do so.

The div is generated by day-pilot scheduler(third party tool)

Is there any solution for this? Any alternative to JQuery Tabs that can handle large div? My IE version is 11.0